# How to use PDO Statement to Bind a for loop index?

Tags: php, pdo

I have two MySQL query statements that’s need to be convered to PDO using prepare and 
BindParam.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the problem:
The two non PDO statements are in a for loop and are setup like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) 
{
    // some codes…, then

    $sql = "SELECT pd_name, pd_qty, pd_type
            FROM ct_products 
            WHERE pd_id = ".$productId[$i]."";

            $result = dbQuery($sql);

    // Some more codes goes here, then.....the 2nd query

   $sql = "UPDATE ct_car
           SET ct_qty = $newQty
           WHERE ct_id = {$carId[$i]}";

           dbQuery($sql);

   // Some more code, some more codes goes here

   // end the for loop
```

Now, for the new PDO statements, I would like to do something like this to replace the two statements in the for loop above:

```
 // check stock
 $sql = "SELECT pd_name, pd_qty, pd_type
    FROM ct_products 
    WHERE pd_id = :productId[$i]";
try
{
     // Build the database statement
     $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(":productId[$i]", $productId[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);//not sure here
     $stmt->execute();

 // more code here....
 // more codes...


 // then the next sql pdo statement:

 // update 
 $sql = "UPDATE ct_car
        SET ct_qty = :newQty
        WHERE ct_id = {$carId[$i]}";
try
{
     // Build the database statement
     $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(":newQty", $newQty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(":cartId[$i]", $cartId[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT); // not sure here
     $stmt->execute();
     $count = $stmt->rowCount();

 //more codes....
 // code continues....

 //end for
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php.

The placeholder needs to be a string or a `?` sign. (But you cannot mix named placeholders with `?` placeholders)

```
$sql = "SELECT pd_name, pd_qty, pd_type
    FROM ct_products 
    WHERE pd_id = :productId";

$stmt->bindParam(":productId", $productId[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);

// update
$sql = "UPDATE ct_car
    SET ct_qty = :newQty
    WHERE ct_id = :cartId";

$stmt->bindParam(":newQty", $newQty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":cartId", $cartId[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

`PDO::PARAM_INT` is right if it's really an integer value. The default if you don't set it is `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Another thing: you could get into troubles with `bindParam` because the variable is bound as a reference. In your case it should not matter because you're running `execute` immediate after the binding. Else have a look at [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) which you can use in the same way.

Comment: +1 but FWIW the PARAM_INT and PARAM_STR doesn't matter.  The PDO mysql driver ignores this argument.

Comment: @BillKarwin are you sure? What if you set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false?

Comment: Yep.  I just tested inserting a variety of SQL data types, with emulate-prepares on vs. off, and with PARAM_INT vs. PARAM_STR.  Every case works identically.  I also read the source of pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c and it appears that only PARAM_LOB is handled differently.  If you bind a stream resource as the parameter value, and use PARAM_LOB, you can slurp in the contents of a file.

Comment: @BillKarwin I also did a few tests but only with emulate-prepares off. What I found out is the quotes are handled differently. When you bind an integer value with `PARAM_INT` there will be no quotes in the query. (A string value with `PARAM_INT` has quotes) And don't forget PARAM_NULL which always insert a `NULL` no matter what value is bound. I will further investigate to know what's the best way to sanitize and handle different data types.

Comment: Great, those are good points.  But regardless of whether there are quotes around an integer or not, MySQL interprets it the same way in most cases.

Comment: @BillKarwin not really..mysql has to cast to integer if you have quotes. So `PARAM_INT` should be used in my opinion. It is also save..if you try to insert a string value with `PARAM_INT` it put quotes around the value and in this way mysql will cast to integer. `'123test'` will become `123` after insert.